# CASSANDRA CQL3 : Set value to entire column

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

For my Cassandra Database, I need to set a value in column for all rows in my table.

I see in SQL, we can do :

```html
UPDATE table SET column1= XXX;
```

but in CQL (in cqlsh), It doesn't work !
I don't want to update row by row until 9500 rows.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Thank you :)

Comment: There is something like static column that can be shared by many rows on the same partition. http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refStaticCol.html Usable if your rows are on the same partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are finding out, CQL != SQL.  There is no way to do what you're asking in CQL, short of iterating through each row in your table.

Robert's suggestion about redefining `column1` to be a [static column](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refStaticCol.html) may help.  But static columns are tied to their partition key, so you would still need to specify that:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> UPDATE t SET s='XXX' WHERE k='k';
```

Also, it sounds like you only want to be able to *set* a column value for all rows.  A static column won't work for you if you want that column value to be different for CQL rows within a partition (from the example in the DataStax docs):

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO t (k, s, i) VALUES ('k', 'I''m shared', 0);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO t (k, s, i) VALUES ('k', 'I''m still shared', 1);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROM t;

 k | i | s
---+---+------------------
 k | 0 | I'm still shared
 k | 1 | I'm still shared

(2 rows)
```

Note that the value of column `s` is the same across all CQL rows under partition key `k`.  Just so you understand how that works.

Answer (score 4):

You can use update query with IN clause instead of executing 9500 query.
At first select primary_key from your table and then copy values to this query:

```
UPDATE table SET column1 = XXX WHERE primary_key IN (p1, p2, p3, ...);
```

Comment: What if the primary key is composite (i.e. there are other clustering keys as well)?

Answer (score 1):

I just added a new column to a table (+60000 rows), and I looked the way to initialize all the values of the column with something (not null), and I found nothing. Is not the same asked here, but if you drop and add the column my solution will solve it. So, this is what I did:

```
cqlsh> COPY tablename (primary_key, newcolumn) TO 'FILE.txt'
```

Open `FILE.TXT` on notepad++ and press Ctrl+H (Replace option), and replace all the `\r\n` with 'something\r\n'

And finally,

```
cqlsh> COPY tablename (primary_key, newcolumn) FROM 'FILE.txt'
```

Note1: You should be carefull if you primary_key contains `\r\n`.

Note2: May be in your SO the lines doesn't ends with `\r\n`.

Comment: Actually, cqlsh allows exporting null values with custom string using _WITH_ keyword.
` cqlsh> COPY tablename (primary_key, newcolumn) TO 'FILE.txt WITH NULL='<null>''`

Where _<null>_ is your custom null value.